# How to implement the wait(); statement properly?

Tags: java, swing, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I'm getting an issue when I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game. The Issue that I'm coming across is presented when I'm trying to use a wait(); statement in order to pause the game so the player is able to look at who won the game and what the winning squares are, however when I try to run this little chunk of code right here:

```
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It gives me this error code right here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at GameCode.restart(GameCode.java:264)
    at GameCode.xWins(GameCode.java:245)
    at GameCode.check(GameCode.java:171)
    at GameCode.actionPerformed(GameCode.java:70)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It describes it to be an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, however I tried using `throw` to resolve this problem but it still continues to give me this error. Any solutions out there? For reference here is my code if you need to see any other info:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameCode implements ActionListener {
    
    Random random = new Random();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel title_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel button_panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel textfield = new JLabel();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
    boolean player1_turn;
    
    
    
    
    GameCode() {
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        textfield.setBackground(new Color(25,25,25));
        textfield.setForeground(new Color(25,255,0));
        textfield.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD,75));
        textfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textfield.setText("Tic Tac Toe");
        textfield.setOpaque(true);
        title_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        title_panel.setBounds(0,0,800,100);
        
        button_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        button_panel.setBackground(new Color(150,25,25));
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
            
            buttons[j] = new JButton();
            button_panel.add(buttons[j]);
            buttons[j].setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD,120));
            buttons[j].setFocusable(false);
            buttons[j].addActionListener(this);
            
        }
        
        
        title_panel.add(textfield);
        frame.add(title_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button_panel);
        
        Turnone();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            
            if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[i]) {
                if(player1_turn) {
                    if(buttons[i].getText()=="") {
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
                        buttons[i].setText("X");
                        player1_turn=false;
                        textfield.setText("O turn");
                        check();
                    }
                } else {
                    if(buttons[i].getText()=="") {
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,255));
                        buttons[i].setText("O");
                        player1_turn=true;
                        textfield.setText("X turn");
                        check();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//Creating the Buttons the player will interact with
    
    public void Turnone() {
        
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
        
        if(random.nextInt(2)==0) {
            
            player1_turn = true;
            textfield.setText("X turn");
            
        } else {
            
            player1_turn = false;
            textfield.setText("O Turn");
            
        }
        
    }//Using a random int to decide which player will go first
    
    public void check() {
        //X Wins
        
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[1].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[2].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(0,1,2);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[3].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[5].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(3,4,5);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[6].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[7].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(6,7,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[3].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[6].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(0,3,6);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[1].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[7].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(1,4,7);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[2].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[5].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(2,5,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(0,4,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[2].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="X") &&
                (buttons[6].getText()=="X") 
                ) {
            xWins(2,4,6);
        }
        //O Wins
        
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[1].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[2].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(0,1,2);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[3].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[5].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(3,4,5);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[6].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[7].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(6,7,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[3].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[6].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(0,3,6);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[1].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[7].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(1,4,7);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[2].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[5].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(2,5,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[0].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[8].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(0,4,8);
        }
        if(
                (buttons[2].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[4].getText()=="O") &&
                (buttons[6].getText()=="O") 
                ) {
            oWins(2,4,6);
        }
    
    }//Stating all the win conditions for the game
    
    public void xWins(int a, int b, int c) {
        buttons[a].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        buttons[b].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        buttons[c].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
        
        textfield.setText("X Wins!");
        
        restart();
    }//When Player X wins
    
    public void oWins(int a, int b, int c) {
        buttons[a].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        buttons[b].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        buttons[c].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
        textfield.setText("O Wins!");
        
        restart();
    }//When Player O wins 
    
    public void restart() { 
        
        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}//GameCode
```

Comment: Don’t use wait for that, it’s not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried to use Thread.sleep(), however it paused the entire program rather than a single method.

Comment: Yeah sleeping in the event dispatch thread is not a good idea either.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what I should use?

Comment: Put the code you want to happen after the wait in it's own method. Then you can use a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) to call it. You could also just make a lambda.

Comment: You could also have a next game JButton so the user can look at the game for as long as he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing too much on the event thread including checking for wins and waiting.  So the following changes will work in a pinch.

First, put the entire body of the `actionPerformed` method in a separate thread.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        new Thread(()-> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            
            if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[i]) {
                if(player1_turn) {
                    if(buttons[i].getText().equals("")) {
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
                        buttons[i].setText("X");
                        player1_turn=false;
                        textfield.setText("O turn");
                        check();
                    }
                } else {
                    if(buttons[i].getText().equals("")) {
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,255));
                        buttons[i].setText("O");
                        player1_turn=true;
                        textfield.setText("X turn");
                        check();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }).start();
    }
```

Then it will be safe to use sleep in your restart method.  You could also use a Swing Timer but it is still important to not do too much processing on the event thread.

```
public void restart() {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   }
   System.out.println("Waking up");
  
}
```

But your overall approach has some issues when it comes to painting and handling events.  You should check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more on painting and event processing.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I will give this a go and add another comment if I am having any issues (if you don't mind answering them).

Comment: That would be fine.  But they need to be separate questions according to SO policy.

Comment: Alright, I will do that if I come into any issues.

Comment: What do you think the trade off is, checking tic-tac-toe win conditions on the EDT vs updating swing components off the EDT?

Comment: @matt I don't know.  I just tend to do as little as possible in the EDT.  This usually means preparing things ahead of time, or simply kicking off a thread when in the EDT to avoid lockup/delay.  Checking the conditions on the EDT is probably cleaner as long as it doesn't take too much time and there are no issues with the effective final requirement in the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using a swing Timer.

```
public void restart() { 
    Timer t = new Timer( 1000, evt->{
        //reset and enable the board.
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
            buttons[i].setText("_");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
}
```

This creates a new timer each time and doesn't keep track of it. So there are definite improvements to managing the code. It hopefully illustrates a way to schedule events in swing.

The error you are getting with the wait code is because you have to be synchronized on an object to call wait on it. You could replace your wait call to a wait + synchronize to remove the error, but it is not good practice and will make your gui non-responsive while the EDT is waiting.

```
synchronize(this){
    wait(1000); 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help here! I was not able to find a method that works for me so I appreciate the possible solution!

Comment: Wait is part of the thread notification system, it is not meant to be used to pause for a certain amount of time.

Comment: @assylias I'm not sure why you're mentioning this here. The only reason I added the wait part was to show what causes the actual error the op gets. Maybe your comment would be appropriate for the question.

Comment: @JohnMcIntyre I've changed this answer to show what you could do. It is better than starting a new thread because it does the work on the edt and essentially keeps your application single threaded. After somebody wins, your code disables all of the buttons, then calls this method that waits some time and re-enables them using an action listener on the edt.

Comment: @matt When you say that it is not good practice and will make the EDT wait, I thought you meant that `wait` works like `sleep`, when wait will only "stop" until a notify signal is sent. But either way I agree that it's not a good idea.